# Is it safe to add a datafile to a tablespace which is being used by a index which is currently in the process of creation?

Tags: oracle, indexing, database-administration, tablespace, data-files

The situation is that I ran a create index query on a table (index type ctxsys.context) about 36 hours ago. The tablespace it refers to has 128gb allocated (4x32gb datafiles). As per latest situation the index is still in progress of being built however it has already taken up 100gb of the tablespace.

Would it be safe to add a new datafile to the tablespace which the index is being built? I basically want to make sure that it doesn't run out of space causing the creation to fail and leaving the index in a failed state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always safe to add a data file.  Me and my coworkers have done this thousands of times without any negative side-effect.

Also take a look at setting [RESUMABLE_TIMEOUT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn10239.htm#REFRN10239).  It allows statements to wait for space, instead of instantly failing.